# How to escape question mark (?) character in PDI Pentaho in a query

Tags: kettle, pdi

I'm trying to execute the following query in PDI 7.1 in an Execute SQL Statement step.

```
update table_x set text = '? rows where update using https://example.net?param=1' where 1=1
```

The problem is that the first question mark corresponds to a parameter I get from a previous step but the second one corresponds to the URL so needs to be saved as it is. This makes the job fail with an IndexOutOfBounds exception because kettle use the url question mark as if it were a parameter.

I have tried to escape as follows but no results:

- \?
- ??
- (?)

But no one works.

At the end I have decided to create a url parameter in a previous step and then use it as follows:

```
update table_x set text = '? rows where update using ?' where 1=1
```

This works but I still wonder if is there a way to escape this character.

Comment: Try with a backslash. `update table_x set text = '\? rows where update using https://example.net?param=1' where 1=1`. Backslash is commonly used for escape sequences in multiple languages.

Comment: @Martin I have used the backslash as I point it out in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This long standing issue comes from the use of preparedStement with JDBC that neither Sun nor Oracle never solved. According to [this blog](http://%20https://www.selikoff.net/2008/08/04/question-mark-%E2%80%98%E2%80%99-characters-as-text-in-jdbc/) your solution is the best.